# Haskell pattern matching list of chars to Ints

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell. I'm looking to convert a list of Chars into Maybe Ints

Suppose I have a single list

```
example = ["3..25.4"]
```

and I want to convert this list into Maybe Ints in the format:

```
[Just 3, Nothing, Nothing, Just 2, Just 5, Just 4]
```

where a full stop (.) is replaced with Nothing and n is replaced with Just n

This is my code so far:

```
yb :: [[Char]] -> [Maybe Int]
yb [[]] = []
yb (x:xs) = if x == '.' then Nothing:yb(xs) else Just x:yb(xs)
```

Not fully sure what to do next / what's wrong, although I'm aware that even if my code functioned that the order would be reversed, so that's another issue

Anyways, the error I get when i execute the code is:

```
Couldn't match the type '[Char]' with 'Int'
Expected type: [Maybe Int]    Actual type: [Maybe [Char]]
```

Comment: I think the example should read `..., Just 2, Just 5, Nothing, Just 4`.

Answer (score 3):

> Anyways, the error I get when i execute the code is:
>
> > Couldn't match the type '[Char]' with 'Int' Expected type: [Maybe Int]
> >     Actual type: [Maybe [Char]]

This is a type error, from the compiler (in particular from the type-checker). This runs early in the compilation process, i.e. way before execution.

The first problem is I think you're not sure what your input is supposed to be. You give the sample input as:

> example = ["3..25.4"]

This is a list with *a single string element*, and it has type `[String]` (or equivalently `[[Char]]`, since `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`). It seems to me that you probably want the type of `yb` to be:

> yb :: [Char] -> [Maybe Int]

and to take inputs like `"3..25.4" :: [Char]`

I think you'll be able to solve it from here. If you have trouble understanding the type errors you'll get, google or other SO questions can be helpful.

One last thing: you are writing function calls in the style of the `C` tradition, but that's not how they work in haskell; you should write just `yb xs` not `yb(xs)`. Likewise if a function gets three arguments it's called like `f x y z`.

All of these are equivalent:

```
yb xs
yb(xs)
yb (xs)
yb ((xs)) -- all of these parens are redundant
```

Also of interest, if `yb` took three arguments then all of these would be equivalent:

```
yb x y z
(yb x) y z
(yb x y) z
((yb x ) y ) z
```

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about your code is that it's working in `map`'s wheelhouse, that is:

```
input  :: [a]
output :: [b] -- where each b matches an a
```

Remember that `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so you'll just have to write a function `a -> b`, which in this case is `[Char] -> [Maybe Int]`. Wait a second -- isn't that another instance of `[a] -> [b]`??!

```
map . map :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

the function in this case is then `Char -> Maybe Int`.

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

f :: Char -> Maybe Int
f '.' = Nothing
f x   = Just . digitToInt $ x
```

(or you can implement `digitToInt` yourself).

Your code then operates `[[Char]] -> Maybe Int`, which is `(map . map) f example`

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of your list is `[[Char]]`, when you pattern match `(x:xs)`, your looking at each `[Char]` in the list, not each `Char`. So when you check `x == "."`, your checking if `"." == "3..25.4"`, which is not what you want.

Additionally, if your constructing a list of `[Maybe Int]`, you need to convert the strings to integers first, before applying `Just x`. Otherwise, you'd be applying `Just Char`, which is not the right data type. This can be done with [`digitToInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) from [`Data.Char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html).

I would suggest making a function that converts a `[Char]` to a `[Maybe Int]`:

```
import Data.Char

one_string :: [Char] -> [Maybe Int]
one_string [] = []
one_string (x:xs) 
    | x == '.' = Nothing : one_string xs
    | otherwise = Just (digitToInt x) : one_string xs
```

Which works like this:

```
*Main> one_string "3..25.4"
[Just 3,Nothing,Nothing,Just 2,Just 5,Nothing,Just 4]
```

Then you could apply this function on every `[Char]` within your list:

```
yb :: [[Char]] -> [[Maybe Int]]
yb [] = []
yb (x:xs) = one_string x : yb xs
```

Which outputs:

```
*Main> yb ["3..25.4", "43..32"]
[[Just 3,Nothing,Nothing,Just 2,Just 5,Nothing,Just 4],[Just 4,Just 3,Nothing,Nothing,Just 3,Just 2]]
```

**Note:** The only difference here is that this returns a `[[Maybe Int]]` data type, which makes sense if you have multiple strings in your list. I also kept the above code as simple as possible, their are higher order functions you can use, as other answers have shown.

**EDIT:**

You could also use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
yb :: [[Char]] -> [[Maybe Int]]
yb lst = map one_string lst
    where one_string [] = []
          one_string (x:xs)
            | x == '.' = Nothing : one_string xs
            | otherwise = Just (digitToInt x) : one_string xs
```

or something more concise:

```
yb :: [[Char]] -> [[Maybe Int]]
yb = (map . map) (\x -> if x == '.' then Nothing else Just (digitToInt x))
```